# Moving element on screen and back with keyframes

Tags: javascript, css, animation, css-animations, keyframe

Provided I have following code:

```
<div class="leftBox">
    <div class="mainNode"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.mainNode').click(function() {
    var element = $('.mainNode');
    if (!element.hasClass('show')) {
        element.removeClass('hide');
        element.addClass('show');
    } else {
        element.removeClass('show');
        element.addClass('hide');
    }
})
</script>
```

and in CSS:

```
.mainNode {
    width: 160px;
    height: 160px;

    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: red;
    position :relative;
}

.show {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 1s forwards;
}

.hide {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s reverse; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 1s reverse;
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    from   {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
    from   {top: 0px;}
    to {top: 200px;}
}
```

What I'm looking for is that my circle moves to the bottom when I click it using the keyframes (I will have more of them in the future).

After the first click the circle should stay at the bottom, this is happening already with the code above.

However, when I reclick the circle, I want it to do the same animation in reverse and return to the original position. Also allowing me to reclick it after to move it back down using the same animation... This is currently not working. It moves down and the jumps to the top and the bottom without the animation.

Any help would be appreciated.

[Here be my example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vJoKjr)

Comment: Does it have to be keyframes? I would use a single class `.bottom` that has its bottom position then set element's original position to the middle or wherever else. Add `transition: all 0.5s ease;` to the element and it will be animating the changes in position. Now with jQuery you just do .toggleClass('bottom') on click.

Comment: I would like to use keyframes since I want to move it, not in a straight line, but in an arc instead, thus having "target points" to pass through. This is just a stripped down example.

Comment: I feel like the fact that the element effectively loses the class before the next one is remove might be a problem. How are you providing the points it should move through and how are you planning on handing variable distance between those points in relation to the time specified in CSS?

Comment: I could first add and then remove the class, but that did not change anything in itself. I am planning on having keyframes on percentages of the animation, i.e. `10% { top: 100px, left: 50px } .....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. I try my best. Animation work top to bottom and bottom to top every time.

```js
$('.mainNode').click(function() {
    var element = $('.mainNode');   
    
    if (!element.hasClass('show')) {
        element.removeClass('hide');        
        element.addClass('show'); 
        element.before( element.clone(true)).remove();
    } else {
        element.removeClass('show');        
        element.addClass('hide');
         element.before( element.clone(true)).remove();
    }    
})
```

```css
.mainNode {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  position :relative;
}

.show {
  -webkit-animation: mymove 1s forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove 1s forwards;  
}

.hide {
  -webkit-animation: mymove1 1s forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: mymove1 1s forwards;  
}

/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
  from   {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove {
  from   {top: 0px;}
  to {top: 200px;}
}
/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
@-webkit-keyframes mymove1 {
  from   {top: 200px;}
  to {top: 0px;}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes mymove1 {
  from   {top: 200px;}
  to {top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftBox">
    <div class="mainNode"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works if I change `backwards` to `reverse`. Indeed! So it is with the cloning of the object, any reason why that is exactly?

Comment: Once animation done , we want to restart it so i use the cloning of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Use backwords instead of reverse it will work for you.

```
.hide {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s backwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 1s backwards;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change two things to make this work:

```
.hide {
    -webkit-animation: mymove 1s reverse forwards; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation: mymove 1s reverse forwards;
    animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

Use `animation-direction` `reverse`, but `animation-fill-mode` forwards. This way, the animation will start from the end, and stay at the last keyframe (which is back at the top).

But there is an additional problem: As soon as the `show` class is removed, it jumps back to top, since the animation no longer applies. To prevent this, you can add `animation-name: mymove` to your `.mainNode`.

```
.mainNode {
    animation-name: mymove;
    // Other properties...
}
```

See it in action here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLgrjW

Comment: Am I the only one that sees the provided codepen to behave exactly the same as the problematic code?

Comment: As Matt says, for me, too, this code is jumping and not animation. It seems more like a hide and show rather than an animation move at this point.

Comment: Hm I tested it in Edge, it's working in that browser at least.