# How to animate an element as it leaves a page?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, animation, menu

I am currently designing a menu that slides in on the right when you click the menu button, and I want it to slide out when you click the X.

so far I have the slide in animation down, so as soon as it renders, this animation occurs:

```
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(50%);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
}
```

is there any way for me to apply this animation (sliding out) to the div when the user hits X and the item is no longer rendered on the page:

```
@keyframes slideInFromRight {
    0% {
      transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateX(50%);
    }
}
```

Not sure if this has any relevance but,
For the rendering of the menu, i am using the useState() react hook to decide when to render in the sidebar menu or not.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46128722/moving-element-on-screen-and-back-with-keyframes) help? For such a simple animation, you might just use a `transform` with a `transition`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use state variable to change className, for example,

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

function index() {
  const [slideEffect, setSlideEffect] = useState(false);
  const slide = () => setSlideEffect(!slideEffect);

  return <div className=slideEffect?"slideRight":"slideLeft">Element</div>;
}

export default index;
```

Also you can use `animate css`
https://animate.style/
install it via npm,

```
npm install animate.css --save
```

and change the code I wrote like this

```
return <div className={`animate__animated ${slideEffect? "animate__fadeOutRight":"animate__fadeInRight"}`}>Element</div>;
```

Comment: This works for the animation as the element loads, but when the element is X'd out, it still just disappears instead of displaying the correct animation

Comment: Be sure please you don't remove the element. If you remove the element it doesn't wait for animation. So if you want to remove the element you have to wait for animation by using setTimeout.